# installing postgres-xl in linux in distributed environment

Tags: postgres-xl

I am very new to postgres-xl. I am planning to use it to my application. There is no properdocumentation to download and install in distributed mode. Please guide me, from where to download, install, configuration, what are the dependent packages for centOS 6 to support postgres-xl, what are the services need to start and how to start them, configuration changes for distributed environment.In a distribued environment, what are the services to start and how. Please guide me. Thanks..!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following are key points to install Postgres-XL.
Detailed information, please see https://ruihaijiang.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/postgres-xl-installation-example-on-linux/

## 1. Plan your hosts, IP, ports, etc. For example,

```
GTM:
hostname=host1
nodename=gtm
IP=192.168.187.130
port=6666

Coordinator：
hostname=host2
nodename=coord1
IP=192.168.187.131
pooler_port=6668，port=5432

Datanode1：
hostname=host3
nodename=datanode1
IP=192.168.187.132
pooler_port=6669, port=15432

Datanode2：
hostname=host4
nodename=datanode2
IP=192.168.187.133
pooler_port=6670, port=15433
```

## 2. Write your pgxc_ctl.conf

```
#user and path
pgxcOwner=postgres
pgxcUser=$pgxcOwner
pgxcInstallDir=/usr/local/pgsql

#gtm and gtmproxy
gtmMasterDir=$HOME/pgxc/nodes/gtm
gtmMasterPort=6666
gtmMasterServer=192.168.187.130
gtmSlave=n

#gtm proxy
gtmProxy=n

#coordinator
coordMasterDir=$HOME/pgxc/nodes/coord
coordNames=(coord1)
coordPorts=(5432)
poolerPorts=(6668)
coordPgHbaEntries=(192.168.187.0/24)
coordMasterServers=(192.168.187.131)
coordMasterDirs=($coordMasterDir/coord1)
coordMaxWALsernder=0
coordMaxWALSenders=($coordMaxWALsernder)
coordSlave=n
coordSpecificExtraConfig=(none none none)
coordSpecificExtraPgHba=(none none none)

#datanode
datanodeNames=(datanode1 datanode2)
datanodePorts=(15432 15433)
datanodePoolerPorts=(6669 6670)
datanodePgHbaEntries=(192.168.187.0/24)
datanodeMasterServers=(192.168.187.132 192.168.187.133)
datanodeMasterDir=$HOME/pgxc/nodes/dn_master
datanodeMasterDirs=($datanodeMasterDir/datanode1  $datanodeMasterDir/datanode2)
datanodeMaxWalSender=0
datanodeMaxWALSenders=($datanodeMaxWalSender $datanodeMaxWalSender)
datanodeSlave=n
primaryDatanode=datanode1
```

## 3. Configure ssh authentication to avoid inputing password for pgxc_ctl

```
This really spent me a few days.

On host1, generate the authentication key file,
ssh-keygen -t rsa (Just press ENTER for all input values)
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

On host1, upload file authorized_keys to host2, host3 and host3, as following,
scp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys postgres@192.168.187.131:~/.ssh/
scp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys postgres@192.168.187.132:~/.ssh/
scp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys postgres@192.168.187.133:~/.ssh/

On every host, run following commands,
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

On host1, try to connect host2, host3 and host4, make sure no password is needed,
ssh postgres@192.168.187.131
ssh postgres@192.168.187.132
ssh postgres@192.168.187.133
```

## 4. Run pgxc_ctl to configure and start the cluster

```
At host1, run following command:
pgxc_ctl init all
```

Comment: Please expand, even if the link answers the question please edit and add a summary from the link here since it might become broken or changed.